# Which one is right to convey sth as what I usually do? "I write emails" or "I write an email"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Which one is correct as asnwers for the question? 1 or 2?

*A: How do you communicate with your friends?*

*B:*

**1.**

**I write *an* email.**

**I send *a* text.**

**I write *a* letter.**

**2.**

**I write email*s*.**

**I send text*s*.**

**I write letter*s*.**

Comment: Assuming that the question is about _agreement in number,_ the answers under "2" are correct: _email**s**_ is plural to agree with _friend**s**_. (However, all of the answers are idiomatic in English. Native speakers often disregard exact agreement in number in everyday speech and writing.)

Comment: I always *send* e-mails. It's just a personal preference (as is the hyphen). I never send texts (unless I have to).

Answer (score 2):

"Email" and "text" are themselves verbs.  "How do you communicate with your friends?"  "I email them."  Similarly, "I text them," is standard contemporary English.

If you *must* use that sentence pattern, then "an email" or "a text" would refer to one instance, and "email" or "texts" when talking in general.

> Have you heard from Bob? I sent him a text yesterday.
>
> Which does your boss prefer (you send), email or text?

However in both cases you can comfortably use the verb forms:

> Have you heard from Bob?  I texted him yesterday.
>
> Does your boss prefer you email or text her?

Note the plural of "email" varies -- "emails" if you are referring to a specific set of messages, and "email" if you are referring to the general activity of sending email.  "Text" is similar, although to avoid confusion "texts" might be ok in both cases.

> My boss was angry with me because I've not been responding to his emails.
>
> My grandmother likes getting letters, but actually she prefers email.

Also, "through email" and "through text" can be used in the same way.  "My friends prefer to communicate through text, " is fine, although "my friends prefer to text each other" is probably more natural.

In colloquial conversation, actual paper *letters* can be referred to as "snail-mail".  But with regard to your question, it's much the same as the other two:

> My grandmother doesn't have a computer so I write her letters.
>
> I wrote my grandmother a letter the other day, but it took over a week to get there.   I guess that's why they call it 'snail-mail'.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers would be understood to be correct for how you would communicate with your friends

> I write *(them)* an email.
>   I write *(them)* emails.

However, without further context

> I write *(them)* emails.

may have more of an habitual meaning

> I wrote my Mom an email.
>   I wrote my Mom emails.